# Extract only one spike from matlab plot

Tags: matlab, octave

I have a matlab plot between two matrices (129 by 1), I just want to extract the only first spike from the multiple spikes as seen in plot. I am newbie to Matlab.

[image]

-John

Comment: Sorry, it was by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Either code your own or use this [peak finder](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25500-peakfinder) algorithm. That one works very well.